# More than one JS button on page with rollover state on page

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JS so that I can have buttons with rollover states and sound effects.  I was doing pretty good until I tired to add additional buttons, which has caused me to lose the rollover state.

You can see my example of one button here: http://www.ultralaboratories.com/sound1.html

And two buttons here: http://www.ultralaboratories.com/sound2.html

For simplicity sake, I used the exact same button twice, but there'll be 5 unique buttons when I'm done.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
title>Untitled Document</title>
   <audio id="audio_element" src="sound.mp3"></audio>
<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio_element");
    audio.volume = 0;
    audio.play();

    function playAudio() {

        audio.currentTime = 0.01;
        audio.volume = 1;
        audio.play();

    }
</script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  <!-- hide from non JavaScript Browsers

  Rollimage = new Array()

  Rollimage[0]= new Image(156,311)
 Rollimage[0].src = "/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg"

  Rollimage[1] = new Image(156,311)
  Rollimage[1].src = "/Images/Banner/e.over.jpg"

  function SwapOut(){
    document.element.src = Rollimage[1].src;
   return true;
  }

  function SwapBack(){
  document.element.src = Rollimage[0].src; 
    return true;
 }

// - stop hiding          --> 
</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
<div onmouseover="playAudio()">
<P align="center"> 
<A HREF="http://www.joemaller.com/" onmouseover="SwapOut()" onmouseout="SwapBack()">     <IMG SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0> </A> 
<A HREF="http://www.joemaller.com/" onmouseover="SwapOut()" onmouseout="SwapBack()">     <IMG SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0> </A>

</P>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're combining HTML5 and HTML3.2 in your document... That's REALLY bad.

First of all, hiding JavaScript from old browsers is a sign you're still living in the 90s. It's not needed anymore.

Second, when you ask JavaScript for `document.element`, which one do you mean? If there's only one, that's okay because it can guess. With two or more, it can't. To know which image was hovered over, pass `this` as an argument to `SwapOut` and `SwapBack` (ie. `onmouseover="SwapOut(this)"`). Then take that argument and get the image from it. In this case, `elm.children[0]` will work just fine (assuming you named the parameter `elm`). Resulting functions:

```
function SwapOut(elm) {elm.children[0].src = Rollimage[1].src;}
function SwapBack(elm) {elm.children[0].src = Rollimage[0].src;}
```

(You could even combine both functions into one and have the `1` or `0` be a second parameter)

Then just a few things about the general layout: You have the audio element in the head, when it's a body element. You are playing the sound at zero volume for no reason at all. You can move the `getElementById` into the function to avoid an unnecessary global variable.

Finally, you must use an HTML5 doctype (namely `<!DOCTYPE html>`) if you want to use HTML5 elements.

Comment: Great, this did the trick!  Yeah, I cobbled some found code together to get this far, and really no experience beyond HTML and CSS, so I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
onmouseover="playAudio()"
```

to each img and not the div.

```
<IMG SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0 onmouseover="playAudio()" \>

<IMG SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0 onmouseover="playAudio()" \>
```

Dont forget to close your image tags `\>`

Answer (score 0):

Add id's to the images, and then pass those image id's into your swap functions:

```
<A HREF="http://www.joemaller.com/" onmouseover="SwapOut('image1')" onmouseout="SwapBack('image1')">
    <IMG ID="image1" SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0>
</A> 
<A HREF="http://www.joemaller.com/" onmouseover="SwapOut('image2')" onmouseout="SwapBack('image2')">
    <IMG ID="image2" SRC="/Images/Banner/e.up.jpg" NAME="element" WIDTH=156 HEIGHT=311 BORDER=0>
</A>

function SwapOut( id )
{
    document.getElementById( id ).src = Rollimage[1].src;
    return true;
}

function SwapBack( id )
{
    document.getElementById( id ).src = Rollimage[0].src; 
    return true;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

For the image portion, a more modern way to handle it is to use CSS instead. Have you heard of CSS sprites before? They are so awesome! They require a little image production but it's worth it. You can put multiple buttons (or button backgrounds, arrows, graphic headlines, etc.) into one big sprite and it cuts way down on HTTP requests.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="#" class="btn" id="someBtn">button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="someOtherBtn">button</a>
```

The example below assumes your image has two button states stacked together (regular and hover). Reposition the background image on hover/focus and ouila! Interactivity. You can also target more than one button with the generic class & then resize/position by ID.

```
/* CSS */
a.btn {
   background: transparent url(images/some-button-sprite.png) no-repeat;
   display:block;
}
a#someBtn {
   background-position:0 0;
   height:25px;
   width:100px;
}
a#someBtn:hover,
a#someBtn:focus {
   background-position: 0 -26px;
}
```